# Best way to retrieve an associated element from a table abstraction in PHP?

Tags: php, singleton, database-abstraction

I'm facing a development choice.
I am developing a book system in PHP. A book has a title and a owner.

In my database, I have a table *tblUser* with keys: **user_id** and **user_name** and a table *tblBook* with keys **book_id**, **book_title** and **user_id** (which is a Foreign key).

I have two table abstractions: UserModel and BookModel.

*models/user.php*

```
<?php
class UserModel {
public $user_id;
public $user_name;
private $_table = 'tblUser';
public function getUser($user_id) {
   $database = Database::getInstance();
   $sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name FROM {$this->_table} WHERE user_id=:user_id";
   $stmt = $database->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
   $data = $stmt->fetch();
   return $data;
}
?>
```

models/book.php

```
<?php
class BookModel {
public $book_id;
public $book_title;
public $user_id;
private $_table = 'tblBook';
public function getBook($book_id) {
   $database = Database::getInstance();
   $sql = "SELECT book_id, book_title, user_id FROM {$this->_table} WHERE book_id=:book_id";
   $stmt = $database->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':book_id', $book_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
   $data = $stmt->fetch();
   return $data;
}
public function getOwnername1() {
   $database = Database::getInstance();
   $sql = "SELECT user_name FROM tblUser WHERE user_id=:user_id";
   $stmt = $database->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $this->user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $stmt->execute();
   $data = $stmt->fetch();
   return $data['user_name'];
}
public function getOwnername2() {
   $user = new UserModel();
   $user->getUser($this->user_id);
   return $user->user_name;
}
public function getBooks() {
   ...
}
?>
```

Actually, from a view ViewBook, I want to list my books and their owner.

```
<?php
$bookmodel = new BookModel();
$books = $bookmodel->getBooks();
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title</th><th>Owner name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($books as $book): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $book->book_title; ?></td><td><?php echo $book->getOwnername1(); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Nom my question what would be the best development choice to retrieve the owner name. In my example, I used a method *getOwnername1()*. I also created a method *getOwnername2()* which calls a method from another model. Is it clean to do it (in a MVC development)? so if it is clean maybe it is preferable to use *getOwnername2()*?
I also thought to use a SQL join query in the *BookModel::getBook($book_id)* and add **$user_name** as attribute to the *BookModel* class. Maybe this is preferable?
I'm trying to do the best choice to have a clean code and respectful with coding standards in MVC delopment.

Comment: Not related to MVC. What you are implementing there is just a variation on ActiveRecord anti-pattern.

Comment: I don't know this pattern (or anti-pattern). I will learn more about this concept.
Thank you.

Comment: The concepts you need to learn about are [active record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), [table gateway](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) and [active record](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) ( though, I would recommend getting the [whole book](https://www.amazon.com/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin/dp/0321127420)). I consider the active record to be an anti-pattern, because it combines both the persistence and business logic, which breaks [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Comment: Thanks for this advice.